# htaccess for redirect files and folder having same name

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I have folder and file file having same name .'product' is my  folder with files integration.html,test1.html and test2.html.
My folder structure is given below

```
testproject (project folder)
   product (subfolder in testproject )

       integration.html (file in product folder)
       test1.html (file in product folder)
       test2.html (file in product folder)
   event (subfolder in testproject ) 
   product.html (file in testproject folder)
```

I want to redirect 
1) /product/integration/ to http://test.testproject.net/product/integrations.html

```
Redirect 301 /product/integration/  http://test.testproject.net/product/integrations.html
```

2) /product to http://test.testproject.net/product

```
Redirect 301 /product  http://test.testproject.net/product.html
```

I have both redirection rule in htaccess. while accessing /product/integration/

it redirects to http://test.testproject.net/product.html//integration.html shows  not found error

Comment: what is the order of the rules?

Comment: @capeStar sorry no such folder in product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RedirectMatch` that allows precise matching using regex instead `Redirect` directive:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(?i)/product/integration/?$ /product/integrations.html

RedirectMatch 301 ^(?i)/product/?$ /product.html
```

Make sure to test from a new browser or clear browser cache completely before testing.

Comment: still getting same issue

Comment: If you're getting same redirect then it is most likely due to your browser cache. Test with only these 2 rules in .htaccess and in a new browser

Comment: product/ working fine but  Product (P as a uppercase not working)

Comment: ok ignore case wasn't a requirement earlier but I have updated my answer to address that also.

Comment: @ anubhava I want to redirect to not-fount.html for all the content in the directory Wp-content

Comment: create a file `wp-content/.htaccess` and have this rule `RewriteRule ^ /not-found.html [L,R=301]` under `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199083/discussion-between-user3386779-and-anubhava).